# opposite of "net use"

Tags: command-line-interface, network-share

To mount a network drive from the cmd prompt on windows I can do, for example:

```
net use z: \\vboxsvr\somedrive
```

How would I disconnect it from the cmd prompt?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
net use z: /delete
```

Comment: "net use z: /d" will also work and save a few keystrokes as well...

Answer (score 10):

Ignacio answered the immediate problem, but one hint: There is a /help parameter for any subprogram of the net command. So, `net use /help` shows you everything you need to know for connecting to network resources, and with `net /help` you get an overview of the complete program.

Comment: also: command /?

Comment: Also: Google, which is what I used to find the answer.

Comment: for some reason i didn't know how to google this one. i assumed it would be "net unuse" or "net remove" or something. but "net remove windows" gave not so good results

Comment: +1 It's always good to show how to find the answer for themselves.